# Using Expressions in SSIS Casting Issue

Tags: ssis, expression

I'm using expressions in the Control Flow to choose different Data Flow Tasks based upon the name o file being parsed (basically loading data from Excel Source into OLE DB Destination).

I'm using the following Expression and its variants to get the desired result:

`(DT_I4) (DT_WSTR, 2) FINDSTRING( @[User::srcFilePath] , "DIVISION", 1)`

`(DT_BOOL) (DT_WSTR, 2) FINDSTRING( @[User::srcFilePath] , "DIVISION", 1)`

`(DT_BOOL) FINDSTRING( @[User::srcFilePath] , "DIVISION", 1)`

I basically just want the DFT to be executed only if the expression is true. There are some casting errors coming.

The most promising result comes when I use this expression:
`(DT_WSTR, 2) FINDSTRING( @[User::srcFilePath] , "DIVISION", 1)`
Where the answer is basically '45' in string form so I cannot use any logical operators or compare them against any numbers ...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just compare the FINDSTRING result against 0 (not found)?

```
FINDSTRING("DIVISION_ABC.xls", "DIVISION", 1 ) > 0
```

That would evaluate to True - just replace "DIVISION_ABC.xls" with `@[User::srcFilePath]`